# The time taken for a particle to return to its initial position involving integration of $v(t)$

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

Here, for part (a), I have solved for $v(t)=0$ and arrived at the answer that $t=6$.

However, for Part (b), the mark scheme given says to do it in the following way:

[image]

I understood why the mark scheme would want to find the distance travelled before coming to rest again, so that when it returns to the initial position, it has travelled the distance it travelled before.

However, I don't understand the following:
Why is the integral $\frac{t}{2}-3$ and not  $3-\frac{t}{2}$? and how does it guarantee that the particle returns to initial position starting from T=6 when it was at rest?

[image]

Please advise.

Sorry for any wrong tags/ wrong layout of question. Trying to improve on it and thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: As to why $\frac{t}{2}-3$ instead of $3-\frac{t}{2}$, maybe the solver is allergic to negative numbers. Could have done it by setting $\int_6^T\left(3-\frac{t}{2}\right)\,dt=-\frac{47}{3}$. The way the computation is done is suboptimal. The $6$ need not have been involved at all.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, what do you mean by 6 not needing to be involved at all? Because in order to compute T, 6 must be included in the second half of the calculated integral? So something like $3T-T^2/4 - (6 \times 3 - 6^2/4)$?

Comment: Alternately, find the displacement $E$ at $t=4$ by integrating the first expression from $0$ to $4$.  Then we want $\int_4^T\left(3-\frac{t}{2}\right)\,dt=-E$.